# Multiple buttons to one Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have one View Controller with multiple buttons. I want the button presses to open my custom one Table View Controller and load the data dynamically. I know I could make multiple Table View Controllers for each button press, but I was thinking there has to be a way to do this dynamically. Let me be clear that another view will determine which data to load into the Table View Controller. I'm new to iOS and Objective-C, but not programming, so take it easy on the rocket science answers. Let me know if you need to see some code.

Basically I have 4 buttons on one View Controller that when pressed will determine what data to load on the Table View. Let's keep it simple for now and just say that the data is 4 NSMutable Arrays.

EDIT:Based on babygau's post this is what I came up with:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"allCattleSegue"]) {
        CattleTableViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.cattleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cattle1",@"cattle2",@"cattle3", nil];
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"bullsSegue"]){
        CattleTableViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.cattleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bull1",@"bull2",@"bull3", nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction)allCattleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"allCattleSegue" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)bullsTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bullsSegue" sender:self];
}
```

this gets the job done but now my navigation doesn't work properly when I press the back button. It gives me a blank screen.

UPDATE: Debugging I see that it is calling the prepareForSegue twice; once with the Controller as the sender and again with the button as the sender. Still attempting to understand how this works and how to resolve this navigation issue.

RESOLVED: Apparently I don't need the actions (TouchUpInside) wired up. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: What does each button contain? Do you want to use their text value or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your table has `tableViewData` is an array.

In each button action, you use the following pattern code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" target:sender];
```

Implement the following segue delegate method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    YOURCUSTOMTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER *tableVC= segue.destinationViewController;
    tableVC.tableViewData = YOUR_CORRESSPONDING_MUTABLE_ARRAY;
    [tableVC.tableView reloadData];

}
```

That's it, you will have tableView display dynamically based on which button you click.

**Notice:** you have to create 4 segue between View Controller corresponding to 4 buttons and name the identifier for each segue. e.g @"fromButton1toTableVC", @"fromButton2toTableVC" and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Hi just create one Viewcontroller and TableViewController. Set the tag fro all button and then create one @property int variable in TableViewController then do like this below..

Create common method to trigger for all button in **UIControlTouchUpInside** .Then in UITableViewController create int variable like this.

**TableViewController.h** file you create like this.

@property (nonatomic, assign) int buttonSelected;

**ViewController.m** create common method like this.

```
-(IBAction)commonMethod:(id)sender
{
TableViewController *tableVc = [[TableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
if(button.tag==0)
{
 tableVC.buttonSelected = 0;
}
if(button.tag==1)
{
tableVC.buttonSelected = 1;
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVc animated:YES];
```

}

**TableViewConroller.m** file do this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if(buttonPressed == 0)
{
tableDataSourceArray = ...
}
else if (buttonPressed == 1)
{
tableDataSourceArray = ...
}
}
```

I hope it helpful for you..

Answer (score 0):

You could pass something like the button label or an identifier telling which mutable array to use.

if your doing the transition in code using a segue in your prepareForSegue method you can pass the value to the destination TableViewController i.e.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        UITableViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.buttonTitle = sender;
}
```

Then in the button handler

```
[self perfomSegue:@"segue" sender:buttonTitle];
```

Answer (score 0):

assign tag for each button. according to tag you can populate different data in table.simply take only one array.populate data to that array according to tag

```
if(button.tag==0)
{
//array=@[..];
}
if(button.tag==1)
{
//array=@[..];
}
.
.
.
```

Now use this array in `cellForRowWithIndexPath` delegate method